# Doctrine ManyToMany Unidirectional with shared attribute. Symfony 3.4

Tags: php, symfony, doctrine, relationship

I've 2 entities: Objetct and Product with a extra ID in each table: officeId
This id is in every table (I cant modify the database )
And 3 tables:

- Object
- Product
- ObjectProduct

I want a manyTomany unidirectional relation.

Entity Object:

```
class Object
{

    /**
     * @var Products[]|ArrayCollection
     *
     * @ORM\ManyToMany(targetEntity="AppBundle\Entity\Products")
     * @ORM\JoinTable(name="ObjectProduct",
     *      joinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="objectId", referencedColumnName="id"),
     *                   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="officeId", referencedColumnName="officeId")},
     *      inverseJoinColumns={@ORM\JoinColumn(name="productId", referencedColumnName="id"),
     *                   @ORM\JoinColumn(name="officeId", referencedColumnName="officeId")}
     *      )
     *
     */
    private $products;
}
```

My problem is when try to insert, insert the officeId attribute twice:
like:
INSERT INTO ObjectProduct (objectId, officeId, productId, officeId) VALUES (?, ?, ?, ?)

Answer (score 0):

When you use a many to many relation ship (either uni or bi directionnal) it creates a join table. You seems to be aware of this part.

This join table contains tow foreign key that reprensent a composite primary key (to be sure of the unicity). This is automatique

If you wish to change anything (ad an extra ID , extra columns...) then you will need to map it as an entity inside you project and define one to many relation ship instead of many to many